# the program being followed works on different computers with different names

Tags: vb.net

good work
I have a project that follows another application.
I want to shut down the computer when the program closes.

In windows 7 operating system = `FasterPos (32 bit)`
In windows 10 operating system = `FasterPos` or `FasterPos.exe`
has different impressions

No problem when I update the code separately for each computer

Do you have a code suggestion that will work on all computers?

```
Public meread As OleDbDataReader 
Dim appcls As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MYSETTINGTBL WHERE MYAPPCLOSE=1", cn)
        meread = appcls.ExecuteReader
        If meread.Read Then
            Dim clsapp As String
            clsapp = ("FasterPOS.exe")
            For Each prc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(clsapp)
                Exit Sub
            Next
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -t 10")

        Else

        End If
```

Comment: I would suggest to make an array of all possible values and check each one

Comment: Why you don't use `-t 0`?

Answer (score 2):

Since they all have the same prefix, you can easily do this:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
     If p.ProcessName.ToLower.StartsWith("fasterpos") Then
        'code here
     End If
Next
```